# How to print a certain field depending on input?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

Say a text file has 2 columns one is wine name the other is a number for how many bottles there are of it.

I want to create a script that when executed, the user inputs a number 1-30 and it will show me every wines name alphabetically that have that number left in stock.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Zach, if the answer you got  satisfies you (and i think it should), please mark it as accepted by selecting the green check mark just beside the score, left of the answer. This way other users can later refer to this question as answered and benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

If your fields are defined by whitespace, you can simply do:

```
awk '$2==30' file
```

That will print all lines of `file` whose second field is `30`. If you just want the first field, the name, use:

```
awk '$2==30{print $1}' file
```

And to get them alphabetically, pass the output through sort:

```
awk '$2==30{print $1}' file | sort
```

Comment: Is there a way i can make it so that it isnt always 30? like it has to be chosen by a user so sometimes it will change depending on the number chosen.

Comment: @ZachP when asking a question, please try and ask the actual question you need. That way, we can avoid having a long back and forth in the comments while trying to figure out what you *really* need. That said, yes, you can change the 30 to whatever you need or pass a shell variable: `awk -vnum=30 '$2==num{print $1}' file`. If you need any further changes, please edit your question to include them.